# Button to Clear Unprotected Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice at VBA. I am trying to make a button that will clear the values in my unprotected cells. I have a protected sheet but I want to make sure only the unprotected cells are cleared. Will I need a range in cell? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Worksheets are **protected**, cells are **locked**.

Give this a try:

```
Sub ClearStuff()
    Dim r As Range, rClear As Range
    Set rClear = Nothing
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Locked = False Then
            If rClear Is Nothing Then
                Set rClear = r
            Else
                Set rClear = Union(rClear, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    rClear.Clear
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**
This will clear the **contents** only:

```
Sub ClearStuff()
    Dim r As Range, rClear As Range
    Set rClear = Nothing
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Locked = False Then
            If rClear Is Nothing Then
                Set rClear = r
            Else
                Set rClear = Union(rClear, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    rClear.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: That changes my formatting. I just need the unprotected cells to go from like a value of 5 to a blank cell with the same formatting

Comment: @Bsmith  See my **EDIT#1**